# Black dots in spectrogram

Tags: noise, spectrogram

Whenever I zoom in on the spectrogram of a recording I made with my phone I see these strange dark dots,[image] unfortunately I cannot try another phone. What is causing them?
They seem randomly distributed and that makes me think about Poisson's noise or some other kind of physical phenomenon but I am waiting for somebody more experienced than me.

Comment: What is this a recording of?

Comment: Are you using a Gaussian window for your spectrogram?

Comment: I don't see any black dots. Can you highlight them?

Comment: @Engineer this is a person talking

Comment: @ZR Han they are everywhere, the entire spectrogram looks like a sponge

Comment: @AlessandroCarinelli Oh sorry I see them. Do you hear anything strange? Maybe you can share the audio file.

Comment: Since you have not responded to my question, I will just assume that the answer is yes. What you're seeing is a typical phenomenon for Gaussian short time Fourier transform spectrograms. Explaining why it happens is difficult. It's essentially a zero crossing of the spectrogram amplitude that happens once for every time-frequency unit cell and is unrelated to actual the signal content. So it's not a problem with your signal.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac that is interesting, I'm not sure I followed but you could add some more details in an answer instead of in the comments? It is weird that the dots look randomly distributed which is not what I would expect if it is happening every time-frequency cell.

Comment: It's not once in every cell, but once per cell, distributed over the spectrogram. Or more precisely: You get exactly one zero for every dimension of the signal vector space. Where they are located depends on the signal. Some more details are discussed here for example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.00082.pdf

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Interesting stuff, haven't paid attention to this before. Also reproduced with non-Gaussian, including wavelets - perhaps it's for any unimodal or symmetric kernel.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon you can get zeros for every kind of TF kernel of course, but most of the time those zeros are caused by zeros of the Wigner distribution of that kernel. Interestingly, the Gaussian does not have any Wigner zeros and is the only kernel that I'm aware of that produces a determined number of TF zeros. There are many open mathematical questions regarding this, so it's not that well understood. But the Gaussian case seems to be distinctively different.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Excuse me but I was not at home so I did not have access to my computer. The original image used Hann window but they are present with Gaussian window too.